# It is possible to schedule tasks with at and pass the current time as a parameter with some operations

Tags: time, at

In GNU / Linux I can use the `at` command, among others, to schedule tasks something like this:

```
# at 07:07 
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
at> To run the task
at> <EOT>
```

Until now without problems the doubt that arises to me is, Is it possible? And if it is, how can I make it take the system time and apply an operation, something like this:

```
#at get_system_time + 25_min
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can - `at` has quite sophisticated date/time parsing capabilities<sup>1</sup>. In particular you can use `now` for the current time. To illustrate:

```
steeldriver@xenial-vm:~$ date
Wed Apr 12 10:56:53 EDT 2017

steeldriver@xenial-vm:~$ at now + 25 minutes
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
at> echo "foo" > /home/steeldriver/at.out
at> <EOT>
job 20 at Wed Apr 12 11:21:00 2017
```

---

<sup>1</sup> including `teatime` for example